# Replacing special characters in csv from stdin

Tags: python, csv

I need to create a program that outputs the rows whose values of column 2 == 'Kashiwa". Lines in csv format are provided via standard input. Also I need to remove "," '"', newline character and other special characters if they are included in the values of "Name" column. 
Here is the example of input:

```
2
Kashiwa
Name,Campus,LabName
Shin MORISHIA,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Omics
Kioshi ASAy,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Genome Informatics
Yukihido Tomari,Yayoi,Laboratory of RNA Function
Masao Kanobe ,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Large-Scale Bioinformatics
```

Here is my code:

```
 #!usr/bin/env python3

 import sys
 import csv

 data = sys.stdin.readlines()

 chars = ('$','%','^','*', '\n', '"', "," )
 for line in data:
     for c in chars:
         line = ''.join(line.split(c))

 reader = csv.reader(data)
 next(reader)
 next(reader)
 print(",".join(next(reader)))

 for row in reader:

      if row[1] == 'Kashiwa':

         print(",".join(row))
```

Seems like my program does not remove special characters from the value of column Name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after `data = sys.stdin.readlines()`, `data` is a list of string.

You process it that way:

```
 for line in data:                      # ok line is a variable pointing to a string from data
     for c in chars:                    # ok you process all of your special characters
         line = ''.join(line.split(c))  # line is now a brand new clean string...
                                        #  that you forget at once without changing data!
```

Anyway, a Python string is a non mutable object, so you have to change the list to contain the new line:

```
 for i, line in enumerate(data):        # ok line is a variable pointing to a string from data
     for c in chars:                    # ok you process all of your special characters
         line = ''.join(line.split(c))  # line is now a brand new clean string...
     data[i] = line                 #  and data uses this new line
```

But if you only want to clean the first column, no need to load everything in memory:

```
 #!usr/bin/env python3

 import sys
 import csv

 next(sys.stdin)
 next(sys.stdin)
 print(next(sys.stdin))
 reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)

 chars = ('$','%','^','*', '\n', '"', "," )

 for row in reader:
     line = row[0]
     for c in chars:
         line = ''.join(line.split(c))
     row[0] = line

     if row[1] == 'Kashiwa':
         print(",".join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the impression you are looking at some Todai page.
Here's what I got. I put a csv file with the data you gave us to make it easier to read.

```
import pandas

chars = ['$','%','^','*', '\n', '"', "," ]
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
dataframe = dataframe[dataframe.Campus == 'Kashiwa']

for c in chars:
    dataframe["Name"] = dataframe["Name"].str.replace(c, '')
print(dataframe)
```

I am using pandas here, it's the best at reading csvs quickly and has convenient methods to change all the rows when you are checking for the existence of the characters in chars table. In the third line you can see that it is also easy to just drop all the rows if the lab is not in the Kishiwa campus. I tried it and it works. Hope this helps!

The csv file looks like this:

```
Name,Campus,LabName
Shi$n MORISHIA,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Omics
Kio%s$hi ASAy,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Genome Informatics
Yuki%hi**do Tomari,Kashiwa,Laboratory of RNA Function
Masao Kanobe ,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Large-Scale Bioinformatics
```

and here is the output:

```
     Name            Campus                         LabName
0    Shin MORISHIA  Kashiwa                       Laboratory of Omics
1      Kioshi ASAy  Kashiwa          Laboratory of Genome Informatics
2  Yukihido Tomari  Kashiwa                Laboratory of RNA Function
3    Masao Kanobe   Kashiwa  Laboratory of Large-Scale Bioinformatics
```